# Не удается вызывать методы WCF из Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, wcf

Сгенерировал прокси классы по wsdl схеме. При вызове методов посредством консольного прложения все работает, но когда пытаюсь делать это из xamarin android, то получаю:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException
> Сообщение = Procedure 'logOnAsync' not present

Выполняю следующий код:

```
        var daisyonline = new daisyonlineClient("https://sample.com");
        var result = await daisyonline.logOnAsync("login", "password");
```

Comment: В [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/wcf) пишут, что поддержка WCF в Xamarin ограничена.

Comment: Проблемы вызывают асинхронные методы. В документации описан способ работать асинхронно путем вызова  методов begin и end прокси класса, к примеру, BeginCreateTodoItem и EndCreateTodoItem, но у меня в прокси классе такие методы не генерируются. Я могу сгенерировать либо синхронные, либо асинхронные, синхронные работают, асинхронные - нет, но как получить класс с показанными в документациями методами begin и end -  непонятно.

Comment: Не пишите в комментариях! Их никто не видит. Появилось дополнение к вопросу - отредактируйте вопрос.

Comment: Add Service Reference > Advanced... > Allow generation of asynchronous operations > Generate asynchronous operations. Обратите внимание на последние пункт: **не** Generate task-based operations